# How to use a tab character within a GPP registry item?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I am in the process of packaging an some software settings for deployment with a GPP. 
I need to include a few tab characters within string and eventually multi string values.

When I paste tabs into the GPP item they are translated into spaces on the client (7, 2008R2 systems).

Replacing the tab with \t, 0x09 or &#009; doesn't work as they are treated literally. Is there anything I can do to get these characters included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with how the encoding from the Group Policy console to the Registry.xml is run. If I open the Registry.xml with an editor and replace the tabs with the value &#009; the policy works as desired.

This is hardly an adequate solution - changing the policy in Group Policy Editor will break it again - but it is the best I've found.

I'm seriously considering setting up a script to periodically change this file and to keep it in sync.

I started a topic on the technet.. Maybe MS will do something about it.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some testing and can replicate the issue. As far as I can see, the only workaround is the one you've posted - modifying the Registry.xml and scripting it for next time.

This is probably a bug (or possibly a "working as intended") by Microsoft.

Sorry I can't help more!

Comment: Thanks Whitey, good to see this extends beyond my environment.